# Wordpress Gravity Forms Entries

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to find entries saved by the wordpress plugin Gravity Forms but I found nothing in the whole db. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong places but is somebody know where are stored the entries (once the form is filled then submitted) ?

Thanks

**EDIT: found ! table is "wp_rg_lead_detail" !**

Answer (score 1):

Entries are also stored in a few other tables: _rg_lead, _rg_lead_meta, _rg_lead_notes, _rg_lead_detail, _rg_lead_detail_long

Answer (score 0):

The entries are stored in wordpress 'rg_lead_meta' table in serialized format.

a:2:{s:13:"gsettings";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"5";i:1;s:1:"7";i:2;s:2:"10";}s:18:"gravityforms";a:1:{i:0;s:2:"11";}}